# Extract tweets and save the tweets in seperate CSV files using loops

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, twitter, while-loop

I am trying to extract tweets for three journalists in three time periods using `zip()` in a for loop containing `cnn_search_query`, `start_time`, and `end_time`. The extracted data for each journalist should be saved in separate CSV files using the `for day in date:` for loop so I end up with three CSV files `2022-02-02.csv`,  `2022-01-31.csv`, and `2022-01-28.csv`.

My code does extract tweets and appends the tweets to all three CSV files. However, it does not loop correctly through the `zip()` for loop as the tweets appended to the three CSV files are all the same.

Can anyone please spot the mistake in the way I loop through `cnn_search_query`, `start_time`, and `end_time`?

```
# A look at the four lists I loop over
date = ['2022-02-02', '2022-01-31', '2022-01-28'] # names for csv files
cnn_search_query = ['(Jim acosta OR "@Acosta") -is:retweet', '(Jim acosta OR "@Acosta") -is:retweet', '(Jake tapper OR "@jaketapper") -is:retweet'] # search queries 
start_time = ['2022-01-27T21:58:59.000Z', '2022-01-25T21:58:59.000Z', '2022-01-22T21:58:59.000Z'] # start datetime for extraction of tweets
end_time = ['2022-02-06T21:58:59.000Z', '2022-02-04T21:58:59.000Z', '2022-02-01T21:58:59.000Z'] # end datetime for extraction of tweets
```

```
# Inputs for tweets
bearer_token = auth()
headers = create_headers(bearer_token)
max_results = 500

# Total number of tweets we collected from the loop
total_tweets = 0

# code that extracts tweets and appends them to separate CSV files
for day in date:

    # Inputs
    count = 0  # Counting tweets per time period
    max_count = 500  # Max tweets per time period
    flag = True
    next_token = None

    # create csv files named after date i.e. index in list date
    csvFile = open(day + ".csv", "a", newline="", encoding='utf-8')
    csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

    # create headers for the four variables: author_id, created_at, id, and tweet
    csvWriter.writerow(
        ['author_id', 'created_at', 'id', 'tweet'])
    csvFile.close()

    # loop over cnn_search_query, start_time, and end_time
    for query, start, end in zip(cnn_search_query, start_time, end_time):

        url = create_url(query, start, end, max_results)
        json_response = connect_to_endpoint(url[0], headers, url[1], next_token)
        result_count = json_response['meta']['result_count']

        # Check if flag is true
        while flag:

            # Check if max_count reached
            if count >= max_count:
                break
            print("-------------------")
            print("Token: ", next_token)


            if 'next_token' in json_response['meta']:
                #  Save the token to use for next call
                next_token = json_response['meta']['next_token']
                print("Next Token: ", next_token)
                if result_count is not None and result_count > 0 and next_token is not None:
                    print("Start Date: ", s)
                    append_to_csv(json_response, day + ".csv")
                    count += result_count
                    total_tweets += result_count
                    print("Total # of Tweets added: ", total_tweets)
                    print("-------------------")
                    sleep(5)
                    # If no next token exists
            else:
                if result_count is not None and result_count > 0:
                    print("-------------------")
                    print("Start Date: ", s)
                    append_to_csv(json_response, day + ".csv")
                    count += result_count
                    total_tweets += result_count
                    print("Total # of Tweets added: ", total_tweets)
                    print("-------------------")
                    sleep(5)

                # Since this is the final request, turn flag to false to move to the next time period.
                flag = False
                next_token = None
            sleep(5)
print("Total number of results: ", total_tweets)
```

Load saved CSV files

```
jimacosta1 = pd.read_csv(r"path...\2022-01-28.csv")
jimacosta2 = pd.read_csv(r"path...\2022-01-31.csv")
tapper = pd.read_csv(r"path...\2022-02-02.csv")
```

As can be seen, all three CSV files contain the same tweets. Note dates for `jimacosta1` and `jimacosta2` overlap. However, that is not the reason the tweets are similar in both data frames as the `tapper` data frame also has the same tweets. Thus, the issue is with the code above.

```
jimacosta1.head()
             author_id  ...                                              tweet
0  1483878706477256704  ...                                @Acosta Love Duke !
1  1452815367206838281  ...  @tomselliott @brianstelter @Acosta Your entire...
2  1454178957931208704  ...  @Acosta Hey Jimbo.  How many of the paltry 350...
3           3365876644  ...  @JeffreyHallett @ConserveLetters @Acosta Does ...
4  1450129826870927372  ...  @Acosta ...
[5 rows x 4 columns]
```

```
jimacosta2.head()
             author_id  ...                                              tweet
0  1483878706477256704  ...                                @Acosta Love Duke !
1  1452815367206838281  ...  @tomselliott @brianstelter @Acosta Your entire...
2  1454178957931208704  ...  @Acosta Hey Jimbo.  How many of the paltry 350...
3           3365876644  ...  @JeffreyHallett @ConserveLetters @Acosta Does ...
4  1450129826870927372  ...  @Acosta ...
[5 rows x 4 columns]
```

```
tapper.head()
             author_id  ...                                              tweet
0  1483878706477256704  ...                                @Acosta Love Duke !
1  1452815367206838281  ...  @tomselliott @brianstelter @Acosta Your entire...
2  1454178957931208704  ...  @Acosta Hey Jimbo.  How many of the paltry 350...
3           3365876644  ...  @JeffreyHallett @ConserveLetters @Acosta Does ...
4  1450129826870927372  ...  @Acosta ...
[5 rows x 4 columns]
```

I can provide code for the function `append_to_csv()` if needed.

Comment: This question needs more focus. What does 90% of your code have to do with the question in the title? Why do we need to know about the csv files you are handling? Why is it important that you are interacting with the twitter api? Please construct a minimal, reproducible example, which showcases the general problem and nothing else.

Comment: Check what you create as ziped data.  `'2022-01-27T21:58:59.000Z to 2022-02-06T21:58:59.000Z'`  for JIKM, then `'2022-01-25T21:58:59.000Z to 2022-02-04T21:58:59.000Z'` - the 2nd date range is overlapping the 1st data range - they may well have the same tweeds because of the thigs you feed your code with!

Comment: your code uses plenty of other related function that do stuff - we have no idea what they do_ [mre] & [ask].

Comment: I understand your critique @timgeb and Patrick Artner. I will simply change the title to something more related to my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I printed the data as below

```
for day in date:
    for query, start, end in zip(cnn_search_query, start_time, end_time):
        print(day,'\t|', query,'\t|', start,'\t|', end)
```

**Output of this:**
[image]

With this I see that, you are repeating the same queries 3 times. Only difference is the csv file name. That is why you get the same content in all the 3 csv files.

Comment: You are right @Manjunarth. I combined the two for loops so it is now `for day, query, start, end in zip(date, cnn_search_query, start_time, end_time):` and moved it up to where `for day in date:` is in the code above. I did the trick.